# How do I get an element in a web page whose name is dynamically generated

Tags: python, html, selenium

So I am making a sort of web scraper with python and selenium, and one of the drop down menus I want to interact with is named different things based on other interactions on the site. It is named like this:

```
<select id ="sel-abfj184h48cj" >
```

Always with the sel- prefix and the rest dynamically generated. What is the best way to access this element? I have tried selenium's find by id, name, and XPath methods , and am a bit stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried RegExs? (It'll only work if no other `id` on the site has that pattern)

Comment: I'm assuming that you've got, say, a bunch of menus, all with `id` values like `sel-<dynamic garbage>`? If so, you can't search it by `id`. And `name` won't work because it doesn't have one. And XPath is just a way of writing complicated lookup paths that you could write as a sequence of those same searches.

Comment: The options you have depend on the structure of the page. Can you always find this tag as, say, the first `select` under some other (searchable) tag? Or maybe the only one whose text contents start with some particular string? You need to come up with some rule that you could explain to a human to apply (ideally one that doesn't depend on things like its position on the screen), and then figure out how to write that rule in Selenium. Since we know nothing about the page, we can't guess what that rule might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CSS Selectors are string patterns used to identify an element based on
>   a combination of HTML tag, id, class, and attributes. It is the
>   most common locating strategy of advanced Selenium users because it
>   can access even those elements that have no ID or name.

To match the start of an id you can use: (Your Case)

```
By.CssSelector("id^=sel-")
```

To match the end of an id you can use:

```
By.CssSelector("id$=sel-")
```

Using contains:

```
By.cssSelector("[id*=sel-]")
```

Comment: That seems to be perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath :- `//input[starts-with(@id, 'sel-')]`

Comment: that is id attribute , OP is intended to know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this XPath:

**XPath :**  `//select[starts-with(@id,’sel’)]`